# Transaction troubleshooting

Tags: php, pdo, transactions

I am gathering data from a frontend form via JavaScript and passing it to my PHP script to save to the DB. There are three tables which must either all fill, or none (with an error). I have the following text wall as my current script (greatly abbreviated for ease of reading) which I thought would work, but I know does not - a column name was mis-spelled, which should have thrown an error, but didn't, and the two other tables saved.

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

```
    //SAVE TO DB
    $conn -> beginTransaction();
    $errors = array();


    //record edit
    foreach($edits as $edit)
    {
        try
        {
            $q = $conn  -> prepare(" INSERT INTO edits ( col1, col2 ) VALUES ( ?,? ) ");
            $q          -> execute( array( $a, $b ) );

        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            $conn->rollback();
            $errors['Edits'][] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    //record action
    foreach($records as $id => $record)
    {
        if($haveExitingRecords)
        {
            //update existing record
            try
            {
                $q = $conn -> prepare(" UPDATE records SET col1 = ? WHERE ID = ? ");

                $q -> execute(array( $a, $b ));
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                $conn->rollback();
                $errors['Updates'][] = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //insert new record
            try
            {
                $q = $conn -> prepare(" INSERT INTO records ( col1 ) VALUES ( ? ) ");

                $q -> execute( array( $a ) );
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                $conn->rollback();
                $errors['Inserts'][] = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        //also record where x...
        if($x !== 1)
        {
            try
            {
                //check for existing record
                $q = $conn  -> prepare(" SELECT ID FROM ifCases WHERE col1 = ? ");
                $q          -> execute( array( $a ) );
                $prev = $q  -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

                if(!$prev)
                {
                    $q = $conn  -> prepare(" INSERT INTO ifCases ( col1, col2 ) VALUES ( ?, ? ) ");
                    $q          -> execute( array( $a, $b ) );
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                $conn->rollback();
                $errors['ifCases'][] = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                //check for existing record
                $q = $conn  -> prepare(" SELECT ID FROM ifCases WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 = ? ");
                $q          -> execute(array( $a, $b ));
                $prev = $q  -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

                if($prev > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //delete case
                        $q = $conn  -> prepare(" DELETE FROM ifCases WHERE  col1 = ? AND col2 = ? ");
                        $q          -> execute(array($ $a, $b ));
                    }
                    catch(PDOException $e)
                    {
                        $conn->rollback();
                        $errors['Delete ifCase'][] = $e->getMessage();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                $conn->rollback();
                $errors['ifCases'][] = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }

    if(empty($errors))
    {
        $conn->commit();
        echo '{"success":"ok"}';
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode($errors);
    }
```

Comment: you set error mode on the connection ?
`$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you catch an exception, roll back the transaction, and any work done so far is undone.

But just because you roll back, doesn't mean that your script can't execute *subsequent* statements. They just start their own new transaction implicitly, and they autocommit if you leave MySQL's `autocommit` variable at its default condition.

You should change your code to `exit` or `return` from the current function when it catches an exception. Or else set a flag variable and then skip subsequent database actions if the flag is set.